# Value undefined during comparrison in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to use the following in a task block in Ansible:

```
when: "{{env}} != 'prod'"
```

`{{env}}` is defined during the initial playbook launch as a user question. However, when I run my script, I get the following error:

> ERROR! error while evaluating conditional ({{env}} != 'prod'): ERROR! 'qa' is undefined

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Ansible when statement](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement)

Try this:

```
when: env != 'prod'
```

Comment: Thanks! I can never keep straight when to use `{{-}}` and when not to.. any tips on how to recognize this?